# Adding an image to the end of a <li> with text, centering the image vertically with the text

Tags: html, css, firefox

I don't use CSS that often so every time I use it I have to experiment again and figure things by trial and error.

What I'm trying to do is place `icon_32` in the same line as: "I made this." The image is 32px high so I wanted to move it down a bit to center it with the line.

After experimenting a bit I found a solution that works on Safari and Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox.

Here's what I'm doing:

**CSS**

```
ul, li {
    /* spacing */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    /* list */
    list-style: none;
}

#work_list li {
    display: block;
    /* spacing */ 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#work_list .icon_32 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute; /* This doesn't work in Firefox. */
    cursor: pointer;
    /* spacing */
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="work_list">
    <li> I made this. <div class="icon_32"></div></li>
    <li>I write, sometimes.</li>
</ul>
```

Because one can't add a `padding-top` to inline elements, I made the icon's position absolute. The problem with just having it absolute is that I have to manually set the `margin-left` because the icon doesn't move to the left automatically with the text. By setting `display` to `block` on the  `<li>` and `display` to `inline-block` on the icon, what I was trying to achieve worked (although I don't fully understand why). This however, doesn't work in Firefox (and I haven't even tested in IE yet).

Is there a proper way to achieve what I'm truing to do that works correctly on all browsers?

---

**Update:** How I ended up solving this by using the suggestions from the answers. Thanks a lot for the help!

I didn't want to use `line-height` because I wanted to preserve the original height of the `li`. I just got rid of the unnecessary `position: absolute` and added `vertical-align: middle`. After doing so, the image was still affecting the height of the `li`, so I just added an id to the affected `li` and overwrote the `margin-bottom` so the sum of its height + bottom margin would equal the sum from the `li` without the 32px image.

This is how it ended up being:

**CSS**

```
ul, li {
    /* spacing */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    /* list */
    list-style: none;
}

#work_list li {
    display: block;
    /* spacing */ 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#work_list #work_item_icon {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#work_list span.icon_32 {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* spacing */
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="work_list">
    <li id="work_item_icon">I made this. <span class="icon_32"></span></li>
    <li id="work_item_writing">I write, sometimes.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this:

You can use negative margins to even out the difference between the line height and image height. The height of one line of text appears to be 20px; so a `margin-top: -6px` and `margin-bottom: -6px` will make the 32px tall image act as if it were 20px:

```
#work_list img.icon_32
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}
#work_list span.icon_32
{
    /* //// SPAN AS IMAGE \\\\ */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/32x32/cf0/000&text=32x);
    /* \\\\ SPAN AS IMAGE //// */
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/92RTz/4/)

Alternately, you can set a line height equal to the height of the image and set `vertical-align: middle` for the image. You can adjust a few pixels using a negative margin-top:

```
ul, li
{
    line-height: 32px;
}
#work_list img.icon_32
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
#work_list span.icon_32
{
    /* //// SPAN AS IMAGE \\\\ */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/32x32/cf0/000&text=32x);
    /* \\\\ SPAN AS IMAGE //// */
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/92RTz/5/)

Answer (score 2):

This also work in `firefox` also please give `position:relative` to your `LI`

or it's better to edit your HTML like this:

```
<ul id="work_list">
    <li><span>I made this.<span> <div class="icon_32"></div></li>
    <li>I write, sometimes.</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li span, icon_32{
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css rule to your li,

```
li {line-height: #px;}
```

play around with the line height to get what you want. Also if using line height affects the image add `float: left;` to it, or take it out of normal flow.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution will be `line-height`.  You can set this on the li, and it will center the text vertically.

```
#work_list li {
    line-height: 32px;
}

#work_list .icon_32 {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the element containing the icon div relative position and it will make the positioning of the icon relative to that container.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9HeNy/

Make the `icon_32` element `position : relative` and it's parent `li` element `line-height : 32px`. A demo is above.

Docs for `line-height`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height